# In primefaces selectOneMenu , I want to show default value as one of the values from the selectItem list

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:selectOneMenu` which is filled by `SelectItem` from the backing bean. Say the list has 4 items: `Mango`, `Apple`, `Banana`, `Grapes`. 
Here I want to show Banana as the default value selected on the page loads. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
                         <h:selectOneMenu 
                                valueChangeListener="#{cust.setRetailerId}"
                                onchange="submit()">
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" 
                                itemLabel="-- select retailer --" noSelectionOption="true" />

                                <f:selectItems value="#{cust.getRetailers()}" var="retailer" 
                                itemValue="#{retailer.id}" itemLabel="#{retailer.name}" />

                            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In this first option will be the default output with the tag noseletoption = "true".